# Badge icon not updating

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

I added this code under "DidfininshLaunchingWithOptions" in the Appedelegate in hopes of it changing the badge icon number each day. Anyone know how i can rewrite this to actually work?

```
 let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(864000, target: self, selector: "sendNotification:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    func sendNotification(timer: NSTimer) {

        let localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3)
        localNotification.alertBody = nil;
        localNotification.alertAction = nil;
        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
        localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day

        //Add one to the icon badge number

        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 7


        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)


        //initialize and send your notification w/ repeatCount: 0 and fireDate: now
        //hide the banner so the user does not visually see the notification if you wish
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two default badges you can change in iOS (aside from creating custom badges).

1. The badge on the app icon on the user's homescreen:

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = count`

2. A badge on a UIBarButtonItem, like a tab bar or navigation bar item:

`self.viewController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = NSString(format: "%d", count) as String`

In both cases `count` was of type `Int`. Obviously the first part of the second statement will change to adapt to your tab/navigation UIBarButtonItem structure.

Does this help?